# Minimum FFMPEG configure options for H264 decoding

Tags: ffmpeg, arm, h.264, video-processing, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a project using an LS1021A board, which has a Cortex-A7, NEON, FPU, etc, which seems to be very similar to a Raspberry Pi 2.  We are streaming in H264 via RTP (UDP) with VLC to simulate an IP Camera with the end goal of extracting the raw RGB frame data (in a C app) to be used elsewhere in the system.

So, I'd like to compile ffmpeg and the associated libs to do only H264 decoding, using libavcodec in C code.  This will be running on a custom linux OS with tight size constraints, so lib size needs to be as small as possible.

I have the following so far after a day or so of googling:

`./configure --disable-encoders --disable-decoders --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-small --enable-cross-compile --arch-arm --target-os=linux --cpu=cortex-a7 --disable-debug --cross-prefix=${GCC_PREFIX} --prefix=/c/Users/labuser/Desktop/build --extra-cflags='march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard' --enable-neon --disable-devices --disable-sdl --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --disable-w32threads --disable-ffplay`

Since I'll be using libavcodec directly, I'm not sure if some of these --disable switches are needed, but can anyone give any pointers on if this looks acceptable or if there are any other switches I should be using?

Thanks!

Comment: You could get rid of libavfilter, muxers, most demuxers, most parsers, libswresample, libswscale, I assume you're compiling not just lavc since you have --disable-ffplay..etc in there.

Comment: I can give you a barebones configure, but I need more info. Which protocols do you need to support? See `./configure --list-protocols` Which input formats for do you need to demux? See `./configure --list-demuxers` Also, do you want to use the plain h264 decoder, or do you want to use h264_mmal?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, bad time to ask a question right before Thanksgiving vacation!  For protocols, I believe we just need udp and rtp, just directly streaming in the video via rtp with vlc.  I dont think our hardware supports h264_mmal.  For demuxers I believe we just need rtp and h264.  The video wont contain any audio.